# Why does give an error raspberry pi act led?

Tags: raspbian

The error is ACT led blinking. It is just like this. 3 times short and 1 time long flashing(short-short-short-long). The problem is not about the micro sd card. i just buy another micro sd card but this not a solution for this problem. This is the error video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uK4tPagAhKQ&feature=youtu.be
Please Help me! Thank you.

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=58151

Comment: thank you for helping me but this not enough for the solve my problem. for my problem, this topic just contains  about the "sd card connector". But this not a solution right? So i just need some another things. Thank you

Comment: I am not going to watch a youtube video to find the details of your problem.  You need to describe the details in the question.

Comment: but this video shows the problem. and i think i explain my problem in the question. but i just dont know how i solved this. i did look every where. thank you

Comment: can you verify the voltage supply? s/b 5 volts.( and is it a power supply from a reliable source?) Also the sd card format might be the problem. There's not a lot to go on here yet.

Comment: my voltage supply is original. but i have try 3 diffrent micro sd card. i use sd card formatter and win32 disc imager for the installation Raspbian on micro sd card. But this not a solution for my problem. Is my micro sd card connector(on rpi) broken? Thank you.

Comment: Hi - looking for a few other clues:  is there *any* video shown - color screen or messages?  Can you test the sd card in another pi?  and btw - is it a model 3B or what? note the link that joan posted looks like it has some good things to follow up on.

Comment: And I found that windows tools gave me a problem where I had a formatted sd card, but actually formatted it with problems in the partition that were a nuisance. If you have a linux machine I recommend using program gparted for reviewing your sd cards.  ( or for live-cd's etc here https://gparted.org)

Comment: From the link that joan posted earlier : "...* 3 flashes: loader.bin not found
* 4 flashes: loader.bin not launch-able (corrupt) See below:..."

Comment: yeah i look the link but link says "it can about your sd micro card connector on the pi". but how can i replace micro sd card connector if this true. and i looking for your proposal. its RPi 3A+ btw. and its showing start.elf not launched. But i dont know what sould i do. thank you.

Comment: @onursen, the video only shows the blink code, which you already described, so the video is pointless